# How to update the link field properties in Sitecore Powershell Extensions?

Tags: powershell-extensions, links

I want to write a script to bulk update the link field `title` and `text` for all the components of a particular type to `Read more` but I struggle with figuring out how to update these properties.

Here is a part of my script which takes all the search results items and goes through them to update the link field text and title but after this code is invoked and I try to read the `$item.Fields["Link"].Text or Value` there is no new value written so I assume that they are not saved correctly.

Could you please point me out what is wrong here?

```
...
$item.Editing.BeginEdit()
[Sitecore.Data.Fields.LinkField]$linkField = $item.Fields["Link"]
    
if($item.Version.Count -gt 0) {
    Switch ($item.Language){
        "en" {
            # I tried different things like below
            $linkField["Text"] = "Read more"
            $linkField.Text = "Read more"
        }
        "de" {
            ...
        }
      ...
    }
    #Trying to assign the new values to the link field but when I try to read it afterwards does not work
    $item.Fields["Link"].Value = $linkField.Value
}

$item.Editing.EndEdit() > $null
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to set the `Title` and `Text` properties of `Link`. Just update your script like the one below.

```
$item = get-item 'master:/sitecore/content/Home';

$item.Editing.BeginEdit()
[Sitecore.Data.Fields.LinkField]$linkField = $item.Fields["Link"]
    
if($item.Version.Count -gt 0) {
  
        #update Text Value
        $linkField.Text= "My Text"
        
        #Update Title value. 
        $linkField.Title = "My Title"

}

$item.Editing.EndEdit()
```

Also, you can set other properties the same way by adding properties. Here are the different properties of Link field you can access.

[image]

You can validate them by opening Link details:

[image]

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

So your code will be like the below.

```
$item = Get-Item master: -ID "{652F3B26-3474-4C79-8A86-AC70CBC26F91}"

[Sitecore.Data.Fields.LinkField]$linkField = $item.Fields["link"]
    
$item.Editing.BeginEdit()
$linkField.Text = "Your New Value"

$linkField.Value= $linkField.Value
$item.Editing.EndEdit()
```

And it will update your link field.

[image]